# Auto Selecting Options from DropDownList Using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a scenario where I have several dropdownlist like the following:

```
DropDownList 1
DropDownList 2
DropDownList 3

TextBox
TextBox
TextBox

DropDownList 4 
DropDownList 5 
DropDownList 6
```

Now, when I select a value from DropDownList 1 it should be automatically selected in DropDownList 4.

When I select a value in DropDownList 3 then it should be selected automatically in DropDownList6.

The ddl groups can go forever and I can select any DropDownList first.

I add a class to the Dropdownlist when it is added to the screen. This adds the same class to all the dropdownlist which are added in a batch.

function setOptionDDLValue(source) {

```
var uniqueClassPerOptionGroup = $(source).attr("class").split(' ')[1];

$("." + uniqueClassPerOptionGroup).each(function(index, element) {

    $(element).val($(source).val()); 
});
```

}

Comment: I tried assigning the same classes when you add a dropdownlist and it works fine for newly added dropdownlist but the dropdownlist that are being populated from the database do not have those classes and hence do not work!

Answer (score 0):

Give the dropdown menus that should share values all the same class, then use a delegated event handler.

```
$(document).on("change", ".myDropdownClass", function() {
    $(".myDropdownClass").val($(this).val());
});
```

If you are using an old version of jquery that doesn't have `.on` implemented, use this:

```
$(document).delegate(".myDropdownClass", "change", function() { ... });
```

or

```
$(".myDropdownClass").live("change",function(){ ... });
```